# Giraph ShortestPath demo never exits, Patch 756 already applied (I think)

Tags: hadoop, giraph

I am a novice to Hadoop and Giraph. I am trying to run the Giraph ShortestPaths example using Giraph 1.1 on our server, which is running YARN. After much hair-pulling, I finally got it to run. Now the problem is to get it to stop.

The giraph process initializes, and begins running. And then it keeps running. I see log messages that state it is running (with a number of containers) and the time elapsed.

I browsed StackOverflow and other sites to find a solution to the problem. One post mentioned a patch 756 to giraph. However, I inspected the code, and it appears that I already have a patched version (I see the HaltInstructionsWriter class, for instance).

How do I get giraph to recognize a request to halt? Or do I need to modify the example code.

Answer (score 0):

The Giraph example should end in 50 seconds aprox., and doesn't need that patch for ending. Probably, there is some problem and it doesn't finish. You should check the logs, for example the Giraph Application Manager, and see there what is happenning with the contaniers created.

Even when you are seeing that Giraph is running your shortest path example with a "RUNNING" state, doesn't means that everything is all right ;)